# Problema com URL muito grande

Tags: java, windows, url, get

Estou tentando passar uma URL por GET e o servidor está retornando erro 404 pela URL ser muito grande (Estou passando um XML pela URL).

Eu já tentei adicionar as variáveis MaxFieldLength com 1677721 e MaxRequestBytes com 1677721 no registro do Windows, conforme o link abaixo:

http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/aa996475(v=exchg.80).aspx

Obs: O sistema operacional é Windows Server 2012.

Comment: Pelo que entendi o IIS consegue limitar o tamanho da URL conforme o link que passei na pergunta ou estou enganado?

Comment: Provavelmente o browser nem manda o URL inteiro.

Comment: A URL que estou testando tem mais ou menos 3018 caracteres, quando tento no meu host que o protocolo está caindo direto no Jboss funciona, mas quando tendo para o servidor que o IIS manda para o Jboss trava no ISS e retorna o erro 404.

Comment: Dê uma espiada na resposta do OnoSendai, sobre a parte do IIS. A minha é mais focada na questão dos envios por browsers mesmo.

Answer (score 8):

<sup><sub>Esta resposta é uma tradução parcial de uma referência do [SOzão](https://stackoverflow.com/a/417184)</sub></sup>

### Resposta curta: mantenha o URL em 2000 bytes

Mantendo abaixo dos 2k, o URL funcionará em praticamente qualquer condição.

### Resposta longa: primeiro, os padrões...

A [RFC 2616](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html) (Hypertext Transfer Protocol HTTP/1.1) seção 3.2.1 diz:

> The HTTP protocol does not place
>   any a priori limit on the length of
>   a URI. Servers MUST be able to handle
>   the URI of any resource they serve,
>   and SHOULD be able to handle URIs of
>   unbounded length if they provide
>   GET-based forms that could generate
>   such URIs. A server SHOULD return
>   414 (Request-URI Too Long) status if a
>   URI is longer than the server can
>   handle (see section 10.4.15).

e também:

> *Note: Servers ought to be cautious
>   about depending on URI lengths
>         above 255 bytes, because some older client or proxy
>         implementations might not properly support these lengths.*

Em resumo, o protocolo HTTP não deve impor limite no tamanho de um URI, e deve ser capaz de resolver GETs de qualquer tamanho vindo de forms. Caso o servidor não consiga resolver o URI do tamanho informado, deve retornar um 414.

### ... e a realidade.

Há uma pesquisa em [boutell.com](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html) cujo resumo é:

> Extremely long URLs are usually a
>   mistake. **URLs over 2,000 characters
>   will not work in the most popular web
>   browsers.** Don't use them if you intend
>   your site to work for the majority of
>   Internet users.

Que em resumo diz que URLs maiores que 2000 caracteres não vão funcionar na maior parte dos browsers.

Em outras palavras, mesmo que você configure o servidor para requisições maiores, ainda assim provavelmente vai precisar fazê-las por outros meios que não sejam um browser, como por exemplo, cURL e similares.

Answer (score 6):

No arquivo `Web.Config` da sua aplicação no servidor IIS, ajuste os valores `maxQueryString` e `maxUrl` para o tamanho desejado:

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <security>
         <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxQueryString="8192" maxUrl="8192" />
         </requestFiltering>
      </security>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Para arquivos muito grandes, e caso a implementação atual do seu serviço permita, seria interessante modificar o seu código para utilizar POST ao invés de GET.

Fonte: [IIS.net](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits)