# Como faço para remover o limite de caracteres de uma URL por GET ou POST

Tags: c#, asp.net, querystring

Estou com um erro ao enviar o formulário, ele retorna um erro de `MaxQueryString`.

Existe alguma forma de aumentar este numero/remover esta limitação? pois no \web.config\ já está setado um valor alto e não está adiantando.

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35573/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode alterar esse limite no Web.Config, mudando os valores da **maxQueryString** e **maxUrl** que são o "tamanho" da string da URL, exemplo fico fica no Web.Config:

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<security>
<requestFiltering>
<requestLimits maxQueryString="3000" maxUrl="1000" />
</requestFiltering>
</security>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

[Fonte](http://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/iis/iis-changing-maxquerystring-and-maxurl)

Comment: é possivel deixar ilimitado?