# Limite Comprimento URL GET

Tags: http, url, get

Qual limite de caracteres de uma URL?
Vejo isso, porquê acompanhei uma requisição GET por parte do facebook onde a URL tinha em torno de 7k de caracteres, pelo que pesquisei, o máximo é 2048, e isso depende do browser, mas em geral é em torno de 2k.

E se não houver limite, porquê enviam por GET? por ser mais eficiente que POST?

Comment: Possivelmente já respondido em [Problema com URL muito grande](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35573/problema-com-url-muito-grande)

Comment: Complemento: [Como faço para remover o limite de caracteres de uma URL por GET ou POST](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43376/)

Comment: perfeito, grato pela resposta @Bacco

Comment: Só pra complementar, o GET e o POST são muito similares em termos de funcionamento. Muita gente acaba ficando no GET pela facilidade de gerar o URL manualmente, mas na prática mudam só os cabeçalhos e a ordem das informações no envio. A maior diferença entre o GET e o POST é que o POST manda as informações depois do cabeçalho, no corpo da requisição, e o GET como parte do endereço, mas no final das contas é apenas um "amontoado de texto" que é enviado para o servidor, de maneira muito similar nos 2 modos.

Comment: Talvez seja legal a leitura disso aqui, apesar de muito superficial no meu ver: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9419/quais-s%c3%a3o-os-m%c3%a9todos-de-requisi%c3%a7%c3%a3o-http-e-qual-%c3%a9-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-eles

Comment: Uma vez vi que por GET é mais rápido, mas a diferença é mínima, e o que vale é a questão de segurança de informação no caso de escolher qual dos dois.. Dados privados sendo revelados na URL por exemplo não é bacana, até pelo fato de existir a possibilidade de ficar em cache.. 
Vou dar uma lida nisso, grato.

Comment: Não consigo imaginar qualquer motivo para GET ser mais rápido (a não ser que consideremos que numa viagem para são paulo quem senta na frente do onibus chega mais rápido do que quem senta no fundo), mas se achar a origem da informação, tenho curiosidade de ver se há algum detalhe que estou me esquecendo